# A proper way to convert rtsp to rtmp with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, rtmp, rtsp

I have a code that streams NVR camera to youtube. This code is done not by me and I don't completely understand what each option does

```
ffmpeg -rtsp_transport tcp -i "rtsp://stream:Stream123@192.168.0.20:554/cam/realmonitor?channel=2&subtype=0" -tune zerolatency -t 12:00:00 -pix_fmt + -r 30 -c:v copy -c:a aac -filter:a "volume=1.2" -strict experimental -f flv rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx
```

On some streams sound itterrupts and is not stable. How can I fix this?
Also I get such lines in the output periodically:

```
[aac @ 0xf1b9e880] Queue input is backward in time
[flv @ 0xf1db7800] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 549844, current: 549779; changing to 549844. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[flv @ 0xf1db7800] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 549844, current: 549839; changing to 549844. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[flv @ 0xf1db7800] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1; previous: 549754, current: 549671; changing to 549754. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[flv @ 0xf1db7800] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 609841, current: 609721; changing to 609841. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
```